# Chroma key with OpenCL and Lode's QuickCG

Tags: c++, c, opencl, cg

in my project I'm using OpenCL with Lode's QuickCG [(documentation here](https://lodev.org/cgtutor/index.html)).

We are having a problemam that, we want to identify when a pixel matches a green chroma key color and then draw the second image instead (background).

Here's the kernel code:

```
__kernel void convolute(__global float* inputImage1, __global float* inputImage2, __global float* outputImage, __global float* filter, int width, int height ,float bias, float factor)
{
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);

    float sumR = 0;
    float sumG = 0;
    float sumB = 0;

    float cR = 40.0;
    float cG = 250.0;
    float cB = 20.0;

    float tolerance = 100.0;
    
    
    if ( (x >= 0) &&
         (x < width) &&
         (y >= 0) &&
         (y < height)) {

        float pR = inputImage1[x * 3 + y * width * 3 + 0];
        float pG = inputImage1[x * 3 + y * width * 3 + 1];
        float pB = inputImage1[x * 3 + y * width * 3 + 2];     

        float d = (sqrt(pow((cR - pR), 2) + pow((cG - pG), 2) + pow((cB - pB), 2)));

        if (d <= tolerance) {
            sumR += inputImage2[x * 3 + y * width * 3 + 0];
            sumG += inputImage2[x * 3 + y * width * 3 + 1];
            sumB += inputImage2[x * 3 + y * width * 3 + 2];
        }
        else {
            sumR += pR;
            sumG += pG;
            sumB += pB;
        }
    }

    outputImage[y * width * 3 + x * 3] = min_max(sumR);
    outputImage[y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 1] = min_max(sumG);
    outputImage[y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 2] = min_max(sumB);
}
```

We tried in two ways, first is verifying just the green color (just for a test) and using this formula that my professor gave

[formula for chroma key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhcDV.png)

Both ways we could not succeed, I believe that the probleam is that the values inside the kernel code are to low, so the green is not going to be 255, actualy with a if statement, we verified that is something around 1e-46

Is there a method that can convert this to a compreensible integer or something that we can work with?

Comment: SumR etc don't get summed anywhere. Did you just paste this code from inside a for loop? Also, a general point, when you calculate the values of the indices, you use a lengthy expression, and do it 3 times. It would be more performant to calculate it once then just increment it for the other two times. Another thing is that branching code like this doesn't run well on CPUs and especially GPUs so if performance matters to you, I suggest you try to make your kernel code branchless or at least branch infrequently within a work group.